# Small Leak on Shifting Histogram Binning

Tags: python, histogram, binning

Trying to pull together some code for analyzing degrading normal distributions against simple percentage binned histograms with the option to shift the percentage bins about a non-P50 zero value.

I've boiled a reproducible example down to the following code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import normal

# --- Defines year 1 p50 distribution ---
p50 = 100000
hedge = -0.10        #percent
uncertainty = 0     #percent
sd = p50 * uncertainty / 100
first_year = normal(p50, sd, 10000)

# --- Establishes multi-year distributions on true p50 ---
years = 10
deg = 0.1
yearly_dist = np.zeros((years, 10000))
for i in range(0, years):
    for j in range(0, 10000):
        yearly_dist[i][j] = random.choice(first_year) * (1 - deg / 100) ** i

# --- Generates bins for each percentage delta from hedged p50 ---
hedge_p50 = p50 * (1 + hedge / 100)
bin_size = hedge_p50 * 0.01
bins = np.zeros(101)
bins[100] = 1e+15
for i in range(1, 100):
    bins[i] = hedge_p50 - (50 - i) * bin_size - hedge_p50/200

# --- Calculates totals in each percentage bin for each year ---
yearly_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, years):
    deg_value = (1 - deg/100) ** i
    deg_bins = bins * deg_value
    deg_bins[100] = 1e+15
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(yearly_dist[i], bins=deg_bins, density=True)
    yearly_df[i] = np.multiply((hist * bin_size), (deg_bins[0:100] + bin_size / 2))
```

Quick summary of the above:

1. Generates 10,000 samples from the true p50 value
2. Generates 10,000 add'l samples for each year subject to degradation (data to be analyzed)
3. Creates 1% histogram bins based on hedge value and p50 value
4. Bins data from bullet 2 into histogram bins created in 3
5. Calculates weighted totals in each percentage bin based on original p50

This works as expected except the sum of each yearly_df does not equal the original p50 value by a small amount. Most easily seen in the initial year as the impact of degradation doesn't show up.

```
yearly_df[0].sum()
Out[1]: 99900.0
```

Its pretty obvious that something with the final calculation to generate yearly_df has a small error related to the bin size changing with the hedge but its not obvious to me how to correct this. The desired outcome is for the sum of the yearly_df above to always equal original p50 total regardless of degradation or hedge value (with the possible exception of the edge bins at +/- 50% which have an irregular size and I don't expect data to occur here under normal use). Any thoughts on corrections here?

Comment: The magnitude of the bias is also very irregular

Between -5 and 5 percent hedge values it shows up as -10 * hedge^2

Outside of this it oscillates somewhat randomly both in sign and magnitude (20 hedge is 400 below while -15 is 300 above as examples)

Comment: Also of note is that the bias increases with degradation even after correcting bin size for degradation (not done in the above code)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - mostly I am an idiot.

Fundamental limit with histogram is that it has a measure of imprecision given the conversion of a continuous function into discrete probabilities. With the hedged bins being shifted being able to calculate exact values is inherently impossible.

The discrepancy is due to the median of the bin that contains the full probability of the distribution being slightly less than the "true value" within that distribution. So for the above the median of the bin that contains 100,000 is at 99,990 so when reconstructing the values it will estimate with this value.

For my use case this is an acceptable imprecision so the issue is resolved in my mind.